# Cisco 3750 AAA configuration troubleshooting

Tags: cisco, aaa

I am currently setting up PacketFence and trying to make it work with the Cisco 3750 switch. I have followed the instructions from this [PacketFence network configuration](https://packetfence.org/doc/PacketFence_Network_Devices_Configuration_Guide.html#_cisco) (except using a different VLAN in the end).

When I connect a device to the switchport that was set up, it asks me for a 802.1X username and password and I have tried both for PacketFence and local user from the switch and it doesn't work. This is my first time setting something like this up, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

The PacketFence logs are not outputting anything, but command **show aaa servers** produces following output on the switch:

```
RADIUS: id 1, priority 1, host 147.32.232.117, auth-port 1812, acct-port 1813
     State: current DEAD, duration 2110s, previous duration 182s
     Dead: total time 2110s, count 1
     Quarantined: No
     Authen: request 196, timeouts 196, failover 0, retransmission 147
             Response: accept 0, reject 0, challenge 0
             Response: unexpected 0, server error 0, incorrect 0, time 0ms
             Transaction: success 0, failure 49
             Throttled: transaction 0, timeout 0, failure 0
     Author: request 0, timeouts 0, failover 0, retransmission 0
             Response: accept 0, reject 0, challenge 0
             Response: unexpected 0, server error 0, incorrect 0, time 0ms
             Transaction: success 0, failure 0
             Throttled: transaction 0, timeout 0, failure 0
     Account: request 0, timeouts 0, failover 0, retransmission 0
             Request: start 0, interim 0, stop 0
             Response: start 0, interim 0, stop 0
             Response: unexpected 0, server error 0, incorrect 0, time 0ms
             Transaction: success 0, failure 0
             Throttled: transaction 0, timeout 0, failure 0
     Elapsed time since counters last cleared: 38m
     Estimated Outstanding Access Transactions: 0
     Estimated Outstanding Accounting Transactions: 0
     Estimated Throttled Access Transactions: 0
     Estimated Throttled Accounting Transactions: 0
     Maximum Throttled Transactions: access 0, accounting 0
     Requests per minute past 24 hours:
             high - 0 hours, 18 minutes ago: 22
             low  - 0 hours, 38 minutes ago: 0
             average: 5
```

Nothing else that I have tried said anything more useful. Does somebody know what is going on ?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the full switch configuration.

Comment: @RonMaupin anything more specific or just full running config ? I will be able to post it tomorrow, since it is not accessible from out of the network

Comment: A good description of how the network is connected (a drawing would be great).

Comment: @RonMaupin of course, I will try my best and will post it tomorrow along with running-config

Comment: What sort of troubleshooting have you attempted?  Do you have connectivity to the Radius Server?  Are services available?  Do you have anything restricting required ports such as ACLs or Firewalls?

Comment: This line jumps out at me: Authen: request 196, timeouts 196, failover 0, retransmission 147.  Can you ping the radius server from the switch?

Comment: @TDurden I can ping, but I have problems with PacketFence somehow managing my opened ports, so I have actually not opened the port that was specified during the switch setup but only 22, 25 and 1443 - and that might be the problem, it wont allow access on 1812 and 1813

Comment: If you've solved your problem, answer your own question with your solution so others can learn from it.

Comment: @RonTrunk of course, I will do it immediately after I test the solution.

Comment: @Jesse_Pinkman Sounds like you are on the right track.  No open ports.  No services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it - the problem could have been in blocked ports but also - I had nonexisting user doing the testing. After I have changed the testing user it started working and the server is seen alive.

Thank you for all the comments

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.